# Multiple evaluation criteria during grid search in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn, is it possible to somehow have multiple evaluation metrics at each grid point in a grid search using the GridSearchCV structure? For example, if I want to evaluate a model both on cross entropy and accuracy, is it possible to make GridSearchCV use both of these?

My first thought was to have my score function (which is custom anyway) return a tuple with two values. This won't work as it's required that the score function return a floating point number.

Another option is to make the score function save the scores in a new field for the second error which my model class would hold.

This is very much doable if I depart from GridSearchCV and write my own function and use joblib to parallelize it.

Could someone suggest something different from the above?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate multiple scores on sklearn cross\_val\_score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876508/evaluate-multiple-scores-on-sklearn-cross-val-score)