# Evaluate multiple scores on sklearn cross_val_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to evaluate multiple machine learning algorithms with sklearn for a couple of metrics (accuracy, recall, precision and maybe more).

For what I understood from the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#) and from the source code(I'm using sklearn 0.17), the [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score) function only receives one scorer for each execution. So for calculating multiple scores, I have to :

1. Execute multiple times
2. Implement my (time consuming and error prone) scorer

   I've executed multiple times with this code :

   ```
   from sklearn.svm import SVC
   from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
   from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
   from sklearn.cross_validation import  cross_val_score
   import time
   from sklearn.datasets import  load_iris

   iris = load_iris()

   models = [GaussianNB(), DecisionTreeClassifier(), SVC()]
   names = ["Naive Bayes", "Decision Tree", "SVM"]
   for model, name in zip(models, names):
       print name
       start = time.time()
       for score in ["accuracy", "precision", "recall"]:
           print score,
           print " : ",
           print cross_val_score(model, iris.data, iris.target,scoring=score, cv=10).mean()
       print time.time() - start
   ```

And I get this output:

```
Naive Bayes
accuracy  :  0.953333333333
precision  :  0.962698412698
recall  :  0.953333333333
0.0383198261261
Decision Tree
accuracy  :  0.953333333333
precision  :  0.958888888889
recall  :  0.953333333333
0.0494720935822
SVM
accuracy  :  0.98
precision  :  0.983333333333
recall  :  0.98
0.063080072403
```

Which is ok, but it's slow for my own data. How can I measure all scores ?

Comment: I would try to implement what `cross_val_score` is doing manually

Comment: Using Python 3.6 this example does not work as the target data is multiclass but the average of cross_val_score is set to 'binary'.
You get the following error: "ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting."
How would I go about solving this issue? Can't really binarize it, can I?

Comment: I used Python 2.7. and sklearn 0.17.  I think this error happens in 0.18. What sklearn version are you using ?

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339523/sklearn-cross-validation-with-multiple-scores

Comment: @NoReply Hi, Did you figure it out about "the Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting." did you solve it ?

Comment: As of scikit-learn 0.19.0 multiple metrics are allowed in the `cross_validate` function. I have updated my accepted answer below to reflect that.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Since the time of writing this post scikit-learn has updated and made my answer obsolete, see the much cleaner solution below**

---

<strike>You can write your own scoring function to capture all three pieces of information, however a scoring function for cross validation must only return a single number in `scikit-learn` (this is likely for compatibility reasons). Below is an example where each of the scores for each cross validation slice prints to the console, and the returned value is just the sum of the three metrics. If you want to return all these values, you're going to have to make some changes to `cross_val_score` (line 1351 of cross_validation.py) and `_score` (line 1601 or the same file).</strike>

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import  cross_val_score
import time
from sklearn.datasets import  load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score

iris = load_iris()

models = [GaussianNB(), DecisionTreeClassifier(), SVC()]
names = ["Naive Bayes", "Decision Tree", "SVM"]

def getScores(estimator, x, y):
    yPred = estimator.predict(x)
    return (accuracy_score(y, yPred), 
            precision_score(y, yPred, pos_label=3, average='macro'), 
            recall_score(y, yPred, pos_label=3, average='macro'))

def my_scorer(estimator, x, y):
    a, p, r = getScores(estimator, x, y)
    print a, p, r
    return a+p+r

for model, name in zip(models, names):
    print name
    start = time.time()
    m = cross_val_score(model, iris.data, iris.target,scoring=my_scorer, cv=10).mean()
    print '\nSum:',m, '\n\n'
    print 'time', time.time() - start, '\n\n'
```

<strike>Which gives:</strike>

```
Naive Bayes
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.866666666667 0.904761904762 0.866666666667
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0

Sum: 2.86936507937 


time 0.0249638557434 


Decision Tree
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.866666666667 0.866666666667 0.866666666667
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0

Sum: 2.86555555556 


time 0.0237860679626 


SVM
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
0.933333333333 0.944444444444 0.933333333333
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0

Sum: 2.94333333333 


time 0.043044090271
```

---

As of scikit-learn 0.19.0 the solution becomes **much** easier

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.datasets import  load_iris
from sklearn.svm import SVC

iris = load_iris()
clf = SVC()
scoring = {'acc': 'accuracy',
           'prec_macro': 'precision_macro',
           'rec_micro': 'recall_macro'}
scores = cross_validate(clf, iris.data, iris.target, scoring=scoring,
                         cv=5, return_train_score=True)
print(scores.keys())
print(scores['test_acc'])
```

Which gives:

```
['test_acc', 'score_time', 'train_acc', 'fit_time', 'test_rec_micro', 'train_rec_micro', 'train_prec_macro', 'test_prec_macro']
[ 0.96666667  1.          0.96666667  0.96666667  1.        ]
```

Comment: It is important to note that the improvement from scikit-learn 0.19.0 is in the cross_validate method and not in the cross_val_score. It confused me and I wasted sometime until I realize it. So, for multiple scoring, use cross_validate instead of cross_val_score.

Comment: It seems to be still retraining it and doesn't get much faster.

Comment: How to use this in combination with e.g. GridsearchCV?

Comment: @Ben take a look at this example from sklearn documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-nested-cross-validation-iris-py

Comment: @huggie I can confirm that it IS faster (4x faster for 4 metrics), tested on scikit-learn 0.24.2.

Comment: What happens if we were using this before? `np.mean(cross_val_score(model...))` If we now use `cross_validate` it is no longer needed to get the mean?

Answer (score 19):

I ran over the same problem and I created a module that can support multiple metrics in `cross_val_score`.
In order to accomplish what you want with this module, you can write:

```
from multiscorer import MultiScorer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score          
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from numpy import average

scorer = MultiScorer({
    'Accuracy'  : (accuracy_score , {}),
    'Precision' : (precision_score, {'pos_label': 3, 'average':'macro'}),
    'Recall'    : (recall_score   , {'pos_label': 3, 'average':'macro'})
})

for model, name in zip(models, names):
    print name
    start = time.time()

    _ = cross_val_score(model, iris.data, iris.target,scoring=scorer, cv=10) # Added assignment of the result to `_` in order to illustrate that the return value will not be used
    results = scorer.get_results()

    for metric_name in results.keys():
        average_score = np.average(results[metric_name])
        print('%s : %f' % (metric_name, average_score))

    print 'time', time.time() - start, '\n\n'
```

You can check and download this module from [GitHub](https://github.com/StKyr/multiscorer/).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn import model_selection

def error_metrics(model, train_data, train_targ, kfold):
    scoring = ["accuracy","roc_auc","neg_log_loss","r2",
             "neg_mean_squared_error","neg_mean_absolute_error"] 

    error_metrics = pd.DataFrame()
    error_metrics["model"] = model
    for scor in scoring:
        score = []
        for mod in model:
           
            result = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator= mod, X=train_data, y=train_targ,cv=kfold,scoring=scor )
            score.append(result.mean())
            
        error_metrics[scor] =pd.Series(score)
        
    return error_metrics
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Apr 2023 for `scikit-learn` >= 0.19.0:**

Since `cross_val_score` method changes a little bit from past versions
As document said:

Use `cross_validate` To run cross-validation on multiple metrics and also to return train scores, fit times and score times

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from pprint import pprint

# Load the Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Create models
models = [GaussianNB(), DecisionTreeClassifier(), SVC()]
names = ["Naive Bayes", "Decision Tree", "SVM"]


# Define custom scoring metrics
scoring = {
    'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
    'precision': make_scorer(precision_score, average='weighted'),
    'recall': make_scorer(recall_score, average='weighted'),
    'f1_score': make_scorer(f1_score, average='macro')
}

for model, name in zip(models, names):
    # Perform 5-fold cross-validation with custom scoring metrics
    pprint(name)
    pprint(cross_validate(model, X, y, cv=5, scoring=scoring))
```

and results look like this:

```
'Naive Bayes'
{'fit_time': array([0.0012691 , 0.00121498, 0.00065112, 0.000664  , 0.000741  ]),
 'score_time': array([0.00356674, 0.00290489, 0.00418973, 0.00282598, 0.00429797]),
 'test_accuracy': array([0.93333333, 0.96666667, 0.93333333, 0.93333333, 1.        ]),
 'test_f1_score': array([0.93333333, 0.96658312, 0.93265993, 0.93265993, 1.        ]),
 'test_precision': array([0.93333333, 0.96969697, 0.94444444, 0.94444444, 1.        ]),
 'test_recall': array([0.93333333, 0.96666667, 0.93333333, 0.93333333, 1.        ])}
'Decision Tree'
{'fit_time': array([0.0010047 , 0.00049806, 0.00131512, 0.00049615, 0.00048304]),
 'score_time': array([0.003232  , 0.00246   , 0.00605106, 0.00245786, 0.00233197]),
 'test_accuracy': array([0.96666667, 0.96666667, 0.9       , 0.96666667, 1.        ]),
 'test_f1_score': array([0.96658312, 0.96658312, 0.89974937, 0.96658312, 1.        ]),
 'test_precision': array([0.96969697, 0.96969697, 0.9023569 , 0.96969697, 1.        ]),
 'test_recall': array([0.96666667, 0.96666667, 0.9       , 0.96666667, 1.        ])}
'SVM'
{'fit_time': array([0.00082183, 0.00068903, 0.0019362 , 0.00088406, 0.00114012]),
 'score_time': array([0.00263715, 0.00342083, 0.00375986, 0.00331903, 0.00372481]),
 'test_accuracy': array([0.96666667, 0.96666667, 0.96666667, 0.93333333, 1.        ]),
 'test_f1_score': array([0.96658312, 0.96658312, 0.96658312, 0.93333333, 1.        ]),
 'test_precision': array([0.96969697, 0.96969697, 0.96969697, 0.93333333, 1.        ]),
 'test_recall': array([0.96666667, 0.96666667, 0.96666667, 0.93333333, 1.        ])}
```