# R-Squared, MSE, MAE as model evaluation techniques to compare regression results

Tags: python, model, regression, evaluation, summary

I am running different regression techniques in my huge dataset which takes a minimum of 8hrs to train. So I want to compare the results of all the algorithms with respect to R-squared, MAE, MSE without running the algorithms multiple times with different scoring technique. I want to know what changes I should make to the below code.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
sv = SVR()
scores = cross_val_score(sv, X, Y.values.ravel(), scoring='r2', cv=5)
scores
```

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876508/evaluate-multiple-scores-on-sklearn-cross-val-score similar question but for classification